How to specify AWS policy where ec2:SourceInstanceARN is equal to resource? (sourceARN = targetARN)
I would like to allow Instance role to do ssm:SendCommand to instance itself but not to other instances.
My policy is:
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ssm:SendCommand",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1::document/AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789:instance/*"
    ]
}

which grants access to every instance.
How to specify Condition element and say ec2:SourceInstanceARN (or ssm:SourceInstanceARN)to match Resource to be equal to. Something like:
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ssm:SendCommand",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1::document/AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
        "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
    ],
     "Condition": {"ArnEquals": {"ssm:SourceInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:*:123456789012:instance/*"}}
}

This is not valid policy
